# are there any methods to get per layer inference time of an onnx model?

Tags: python, neural-network, onnx, onnxruntime

The code is like

```py
import onnxruntime

onnx_input= np.random.normal(size=[1, 3, 224, 224]).astype(np.float32)
ort_sess = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('model.onnx')
ort_inputs = {ort_sess.get_inputs()[0].name: onnx_input}
ort_outs = ort_sess.run(None, ort_inputs)
```

I can get the network output from ort_outs, but how can I get the infernce time of each layer of the model?

I can get the model graph info by

```py
import onnx
model = onnx.load("model.onnx")
print(onnx.helper.printable_graph(model.graph))
```

or get the total inference time by

```py
import time

start = time.time()
ort_outs = ort_sess.run(None, ort_inputs)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

but I don't know how to get the inference time per layer of the neural network. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/performance/tune-performance/profiling-tools.html for details on enabling profiling of individual nodes.

Note that the overall inference time will be meaningless when it is measuring per-node performance due to the overhead of outputting the profiling data.